# Исключение в regex php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть такое регулярное выражение:

```
<(img)([^>]+?)(>(.*?)<\/\\1>|[\/]?>)
```

Оно выбирает все теги `<img>` из текста. Но мне нужно выбирать эти теги, исключая те, у которых есть класс noSelect. Сделал так:

```
<(img)([^>]+?)(?!\"noSelect\")(>(.*?)<\/\\1>|[\/]?>)
```

Но не работает. Как исправить? Спасибо.

Comment: Сложное условие для regex, лучше условие "содержит". Потому что "не содержит" - имеет большую нагрузку - возможно прийдётся даже ограничить глубину поиска. Если выражение уже найдено - то оно найдено, и "отменить каст"... сложно. Ошибка у вас - `([^>]+?)` - уже кастит по "конец тега". А что что следует дальше - это "лишнее". Попробуйте сформулировать задачу (не регех нужен, а... ) - а тогда уже может и прийдёт решение.

Comment: Я пытался найти другой решение, но в данном случае его нет. Так как использую плагин LazyLoad для WordPress. А он преобразует все картинки. Мне это не нужно. У меня есть слайдер изображений, который должен быть без изменений. Вот и добавил в них специальный класс, который будет игнорироваться у LazyLoad.

Comment: Я нашёл кусок кода, который отвечает за преобразование. А там как раз и используется данное регулярное выражение.

Comment: Может проще будет - получить список img, а там просто перелопатить список строковой проверкой?

Comment: Не работает потому что `noSelect` подпадает под `([^>]+?)`

Comment: В общем, наверное, я просто удалю этот плагин и напишу свой с использованием более простых регулярок. Спасибо за то, что пытались помочь))

Comment: Регулярки - не панацея. Иногда удобно, иногда - нет. Иногда нужна токенизация (разбор скрипта, так работает PHP). Для XML, HTML хорошо работает Xpath. Я бы сделал `preg_match_all`, а затем `array_filer`. Вы бы показали те строчки плагина, а то пытаетесь решить проблему A, решая проблему B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прописал на всякий случай выбор не захвата атрибутов `id` и `class` со значением `noSelect`:

```
/<img(?:(?!(?:id|class)="noSelect")[^>])*>/i
```

*[См. демо](https://regex101.com/r/U8wmbZ/1)* регулярного выражения.

Answer (score 2):

Подсмотрев в лучший ответ [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word), думаю тебе подойдет такой вариант:

```
<(img)(((?!noSelect)[^>])+?)(>(.*?)<\/\\1>|[\/]?>)
```